# elasticsearch query pagination

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, mongoosastic

I use mongoosastic for elasticsearch query with node.js and mongoDB.

When I try this query all goes well

```
query_string: {
        query: query['search']
    }
}
```

But when I want to add pagination I get an errors

```
query_string: {
        query: query['search']
    },
    size: 1,
    from: 1
}
```

On this query it gives me error

> [parse_exception] failed to parse search source. expected field name but got [VALUE_NUMBER]

And on this query gives this error

```
options.elasticQuery = {
    size: 1,
    from: 1,
    query_string: {
        query: query['search']
    }
}
```

> [query_parsing_exception] [_na] query malformed, no field after start_object, with { index=users line=1 col=11 }

This is how I create request

```
ModelName.search(options.elasticQuery, (err, res) => {
    console.log(err, res);
})
```

Comment: What are the values of `options.page` and `options.limit`? And can you post the actual query that you;re using?

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin updated

Comment: Are you querying ES using http rest api or through elasticsearch,js lib? Can you show the code of `ModelName.search`?

Comment: I am using mongoosastic module for node.js
But I found problem just now, thank you. The problem is that skip and limit must give in other object as second parameter for search function.